# Calculate mode on a dataframe without sorting the result

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mode

I have a data frame like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a1': [2,3,4,8,8], 'a2': [2,5,7,5,10], 'a3':[1,9,4,10,2]})

    a1  a2  a3
0   2   2   1
1   3   5   9
2   4   7   4
3   8   5   10
4   8   10  2
```

The output should be:

```
0  2 
1  3
2  4
3  8 
4  8
```

What to do: I want to calculate mode row-wise, and if the mode is not present, I want the value from a1 (first column).

For example: In second row `(3,5,9)`, the mode is not present so I get `3` in output.

### **Note: I've already tried `df.mode(axis=1)` but that seems to shuffle the sequence of values row wise, so I don't always get the value of first column in the output.**

Comment: I've updated the question. The tricky part was missing. I don't think it's a duplicate.

Comment: By "mode not present" you mean that there is a tie?

Comment: @BallpointBen Yes exactly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No-Sort Methods**

`agg` + `collections.Counter`. *Does not sort the modes*.

```
from collections import Counter
df.agg(lambda x: Counter(x).most_common(1)[0][0], axis=1)

0    2
1    3
2    4
3    8
4    8
dtype: int64
```

---

**Mode Sorting Methods**

1. Use `mode` along the first axis and then take whatever comes first:

   ```
   df.mode(axis=1).iloc[:, 0]
   ```

   Or,

   ```
   df.mode(axis=1)[0]
   ```

   ```
   0    2.0
   1    3.0
   2    4.0
   3    5.0
   4    2.0
   Name: 0, dtype: float64
   ```
2. `scipy.stats.mode`

   ```
   from scipy.stats import mode
   np.array(mode(df, axis=1))[0].squeeze()
   array([2, 3, 4, 5, 2])
   ```

Comment: Why not just `df.mode(axis=1)[0]`?

Comment: Please check note in the question. Sorry I should have updated this initially.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ your answer fails on some cases. I've updated the df with new row. Please check.

Comment: @ManishSaraswat Hi , if this is what you need , can you consider accept it ?

Comment: @ManishSaraswat I pulled out every trick I had to get you option 3

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ and that finally solves the problem. I'll accept your answer because you didn't give up.

Answer (score 3):

One more option is to use `np.where`:

```
mode = df.mode(axis=1)
np.where(mode.iloc[:,-1].isnull(),
    mode.iloc[:,0], # No tie, use the calculated mode 
    df.iloc[:,0]) # Tie, use the first column of the original df
# array([2., 3., 4., 8., 8.])
```